# Negative flags in C#

Tags: c#, enums, flags

Hey, is there any way to store negative flags in C#? For example I have the following flags enum that represents some styles:

```
[Flags]
public enum Styles
{
    Default = 0,
    Bold = 1,
    Italic = 2
}
```

Now I have multiple objects, those styles can be applied to, and later all related are combined (i.e. other object may inherit some previously set styles). In addition to that, I would like to define negative flags, that basically undo inherited styles. So if the style was previously set to `Styles.Bold | Styles.Italic` and the object inherits that style but has a negative `Styles.Bold` flag set, then the result should be just `Styles.Italic`.

Is there any mechanism that already does this? I basically though of two ways now: First is defining `NotXY` enum values, that are then somehow parsed to eliminate the `XY` values if set.

The other is simply defining two fields, positive and negative flags, where the negative flags are specially defined in an extra field and I get the resulting flags by simply doing `positiveFlags ^ negativeFlags`.

#### edit:

If this wasn't clear, I need to store each of those intermediate objects' styles. So it could be for example like this:

```
object1: Default
object2: Bold
object3: -Bold Italic
```

And if object3 also inherits the values of 1 and 2, then the final result should be just `Italic`.

Another example in response to Kieren Johnstone's question, and per my statement in the comment that negative values only apply on the current level:

```
1: Bold
2: -Bold -Italic
3: Italic
```

2 eliminates both Bold and Italic from previous objects, but then shouldn't apply any further (positive values should though), so the final value would be `Italic` again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So should the negative always have precedence?  What if you start with a `NotBold` and then add a `Bold`?

If it's always positive overridden by negative when present, I'd suggest two fields:

```
private Styles baseStyles;
private Styles overrideDisableStyles;
public Styles ResultsStyles { return baseStyles & ~overrideDisableStyles; }
```

Or you could create a helper class with `SetStyle` and `UnsetStyle`:

```
public void SetStyle(Styles styles)
{
    this.styles |= styles;
}

public void UnsetStyle(Styles styles)
{
    this.styles &= ~styles;
}
```

For reference, `positiveFlags ^ negativeFlags` will NOT work.  Consider the situation where `Bold` is not set but `NotBold` is.  The result will be `Bold` even though the only specified flag was `NotBold`.

Finally, if you're doing anything commerical, in-depth, any more complex than you describe here and want to have extendable/expandable style inheritance, you should design it correctly with an object graph/class hierarchy - start by defining a `Style` class that has one or more parent objects.  Each `Style` could have a set of property name/value pairs that override anything from the parent - there could be a `Properties` collection that returns these overrides, and an `Evaluate` method that starts at the root object and navigates to the style in question, building a resulting list of properties for you to use.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very good point I didn't consider yet. I guess in my case I only want positive values to be inherited, so negative values will only apply on the current "level" (they still need to be stored appropriately).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend going with the second approach. It seems more obvious and simpler to me.

Answer (score 1):

> The other is simply defining two fields, positive and negative flags, where the negative flags are specially defined in an extra field and I get the resulting flags by simply doing `positiveFlags ^ negativeFlags`.

This seems most natural for me (except the expression shoud read `positiveFlags & ~negativeFlags`). Additionally it leads to a simple method of applying inherited styles. If we rewrite your example

```
1: Bold
2: -Bold -Italic
3: Italic
```

as (no specific syntax...)

```
1: pos:{ Bold }   neg:{ none }
2: pos:{ none }   neg:{ Bold Italic }
3: pos:{ Italic } neg:{ none }
```

then effective styles are calculated with inheritance as `(prevLevelStyle | pos) & ~neg`, resulting in:

```
1: ({ none } | { Bold })   & ~{ none }        = { Bold }
2: ({ Bold } | { none })   & ~{ Bold Italic } = { none }
3: ({ none } | { Italic }) & ~{ none }        = { Italic }
```

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you do not nesessary need to define negative flags, but use "positive" flags to unset them.

For example, this code can be used to unset Bold flag

```
Styles styles = Styles.Bold | Styles.Italic;
styles = styles ^ Styles.Bold;
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to store the negative values somehow until they are used for the final calculation of the value.

Comment: The second line toggles Bold, doesn't always exclude it (in your specific example it does though).  Better to `styles &= ~Styles.Bold;` in all cases, which always unsets it.